# Conversión de microsegundos en formato horas, minutos y segundos

Tags: java

Necesito ayuda para crear un cronometro formato reloj con horas minutos y segundo pero el inconveniente que tengo es que este siguiente método me da el tiempo el microsegundos.

```
    public void progress(int bytesread, long microseconds, byte[] pcmdata, Map arg1) {
   System.out.println(microseconds); }
```

Además no puedo colocar *microseconds* en cero ya que ya lo intente pero no sé puede es un método que da la librería que estoy usando y no se puede colocar en ceros.

¿Cómo podría convertir los microsegundos en **formato** horas, minutos y segundos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede que sea algo asi

```
int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000000) % 60 ;
int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000000*60)) % 60);
int hours   = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000000*60*60)) % 24);
```

Comment: muchas gracias si me funciono. :) saludos.